# Do undecidable problems have no HO query? If so, could I have an example?

Tags: undecidability, complexity-classes, descriptive-complexity

In [descriptive complexity, HO corresponds to ELEMENTARY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_complexity_theory).

[ELEMENTARY is a subset of R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELEMENTARY), so therefore all HO queries are decidable.

Then undecidable problems have no corresponding HO query.  Is my understanding correct?  If so, can I have an example undecidable problem and an intuitive/informal explanation of why it doesn't have a corresponding HO query?